# How to send a private transaction using Quorum

Tags: transactions, quorum

I'm trying to send a private transaction using  Quorum geth, but  eventually got an error :

```
Error: ether value is not supported for private transactions
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I notice that Quorum can't transfer balance privately, as this [issuse](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/201) mentioned

But  even if I specify ether value to `0`, the error still remain :

```js
> eth.sendTransaction({
    from: eth.accounts[0],
    to: "0xca843569e3427144cead5e4d5999a3d0ccf92b8e", 
    privateFor:["QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc="], 
    value: 0
})
```

---

Enviroment :

```
Geth
Version: 1.8.18-stable
Git Commit: 51e1f6354665ed7f6b098bf53ce3fd5944e14cb6
Quorum Version: 2.4.0
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1337
Go Version: go1.13.5
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/tmp2/go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private txns in Quorum are designed to be executed over private contracts, we have many examples, but I'd recommend starting on this page to understand how its done: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/7nodes#demonstrating-privacy.

And as you've noticed, no value transfers are allowed in private mode at all. If you need to track balances privately, please examine 5nodeRTGS example: https://github.com/bacen/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/5nodesRTGS